# I seem to have installed two OS by mistake

Tags: system-installation

I am a newbie to this LINUX/Ubuntu business and just a couple of days installed Ubuntu from a minimal install. I didn't really know what all the installation options meant and I seem to have clicked too many. Ubuntu is running very slow and when I boot up it gives me the choice of using Ubuntu Gnome or Ubuntu classic. Have I installed two OS by mistake? Is thee an easy way to get rid of one?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't install two OSs.

Ubuntu Gnome comes with two desktop options, the classic version being faster.

If you have an old machine, it is recommended you try the lighter versions Xubuntu or Lubuntu instead of Ubuntu Gnome.

Comment: +1, but the specific phrase is two [desktop environments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment).

Comment: thank you for that, I am glad you cleared up the difference for me. Could part of the problem be all software packages I opted in for? Is it worth my time to go and uninstall all the programmes I don't need?

Comment: @YorkshireNed Mostly extra packages should just waste disk space.